# Pascal's triangle works but throws an Notices

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, notice, pascals-triangle

Here is my script. The program can't find values in `$tri` array when I do `$somma=$tri[$y]+$tri[$z];`?

I keep getting Notices, but why?

```
<?php
$tri=array(1,1);
for ($x=0;$x<=6;$x++) {
    print_r($tri);
    $count=count($tri);
    $trinew=array();
    for($y=0;$y<$count;$y++) {
        $z=$y+1;
        $somma=$tri[$y]+$tri[$z];    // <-- here is the problem
        array_push($trinew,$somma);
    }
    array_unshift($trinew, 1);
    $tri=$trinew;
}
?>
```

Comment: You can fill these empty lines with explanation about the code, what the expected output and the actual one, because I quite agree -  This code is not readable to me too. Please [edit] your post and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$y` = `$count - 1`, then `$z` = `$count` and there is never an element available via `$tri[$z]`.

For example, on the first iteration of `$x`, `$tri` is:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 1,
)
```

When `$y = 0` and `$z = 1` everything is fine, but when the nested `for()` moves to its final iteration (`$y = 1` and `$z = 2`), `$tri` doesn't have a `2` index.

This is why you are receiving *Notices*.

---

With a null coalescing operator and some other minor touches, this seems to run smoothly:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ugcIo))

```
$tri = [1, 1];
for ($x = 0; $x <= 6; ++$x) {
    var_export($tri);
    $trinew = [1];
    for($y = 0, $count = count($tri); $y < $count; ++$y) {
        $z = $y + 1;
        $trinew[] = $tri[$y]  + ($tri[$z] ?? 0);
    }
    $tri = $trinew;
}
```

---

Or you could push a `0` element into `$tri` before the inner for loop and subtract 1 from the `count()`.  https://3v4l.org/sWcrr

Comment: thank you, but i didn't understand ($tri[$z] ?? 0), what's the function of "??"  ?

Comment: The null coalescing operator (new to php 7+) is a succinct way to write `issest($tri[$z]) ? $tri[$z] : 0`. Effectively, if the element exists, use the element's value, if not use `0` as the fallback value.  Here's another way without the null coalescing operator: https://3v4l.org/E23r7